# undefined method `create' in Rails RSpec

Tags: rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have installed FactoryBot and trying to use it with RSpec.

```ruby
scenario 'User signs in' do
  create :user, email: 'test@example.com', password: 'testpassword'
  visit '/users/sign_in'

  fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@example.com'
  fill_in 'Password', with: 'testpassword'
end
```

and I am getting the following error.

```
Failure/Error: create :user, email: 'test@example.com', password: 'testpassword'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserSignIn:0x007fe6324816b8>
```

Comment: Try `FactoryGirl.create`

Answer (score 46):

We can find solution in [factory_bot's documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rspec):

**1)** Create file */spec/support/factory_bot.rb*:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

**2)** Edit */spec/rails_helper.rb* to load all files in *support* directory:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Answer (score 15):

In my case I was missing `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` in `rails_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1):

go to /spec/rails_helper.rb and search for
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
and uncomment it