# undefined method create for RSpec rails 5

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot, rspec-rails

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829440/undefined-method-create-rails-spec) may a possible duplicate however it did not work for me.
Please let me know what did I miss.

**Config details:**

```
#Gemfile
gem 'factory_bot_rails' # 4.8.2

#spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  #other config
end
```

**spec/factories/otps.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :otp do
    phone { Faker::Number.number(10) }
    expiry { Time.now + Otp::Constants::EXPIRY_DURATION }
    password { Faker::Number.number(4) }
  end
end
```

**spec/requests/authentication_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
RSpec.describe "Authentication", :type => :request do
  describe "when invalid OTP is passed" do
    it "should return bad request" do
      otp = create(:otp) # ===> Throws error
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your spec to include the right helper:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Authentication", :type => :request do
  describe "when invalid OTP is passed" do
    it "should return bad request" do
      otp = create(:otp)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also skip that line, if you use a `.rspec` file, which would include something like:

```
 --color
 --format progress
 --order random
 --require rails_helper
```